# Use Array.prototype.map in a functional, covariant way

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, prototype-programming, array.prototype.map

> Say I have the following input (to be used with `Node`, but the problem is more general, and not Node related):
>
> - Absolute path to a directory, call it `dirPathAbs`
> - An array of basenames (call it `namesSeq`) of some JS files that exist inside that folder

#### For example:

I might have `namesSeq = ['a', 'b', 'c']` which corresponds to some `a.js`, `b.js`, `c.js` inside `dirPathAbs`.

#### Problem:

How do I resolve the paths of the files, in a purely **functional way**, but also in a **covariant way**? (i.e. without having to ever talk about a variable that iterates the array. ***Covariant*** might not be the word for this, sorry).

#### What I don't want:

```
namesSeq.map(base => path.join(dirPathAbs, `${base}.js`));
```

Nor

```
namesSeq.map(base => require.resolve(path.join(dirPathAbs, base)));
```

Nor

```
namesSeq.map(base => path.resolve.bind(dirPathAbs)(base));
```

Nor

```
const cb = base => path.resolve.bind(dirPathAbs)(base);
namesSeq.map(cb);
```

#### I was expecting this one to work

```
namesSeq.map(path.resolve.bind(dirPathAbs))
```

but it doesn't. I think `path.resolve.bind(dirPathAbs)` receives as input `namesSeq`, which is the 3rd param of the callback provided to `Array.prototype.map`, because the error I see is

```
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

This is just one exercise of this kind that frustrates me, but a whole category of analogous exercises gave me headaches since learning JS. I am still missing something when it comes to how `this` binds, and how all these `Function.prototype`, `Array.prototype` & friends should be used.

Comment: Why don't you want any of those solutions?

Comment: The quick answer is "for the sake of the exercise", but I have another reason. I'll try to clearly formulate it in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another function in the middle to eat up those extra variables:

```
 const take = (fn, n) => (...args) => fn(...args.slice(0, n));
 const bind = fn => (...args) => (...args2) => fn(...args, ...args2);

 namesSeq.map(take(bind(path.resolve)(dirPathAbs), 1));
```

but I don't see any advatange over a named parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be an assumption about `namesSeq` that is partially at fault here. Here's a very simple example that more or less follows what you're doing. You can see when you run the snippet that it works as expected:

```js
function mockResolve(input) {
  console.log(input)
  return input * 2;
}

var scopeObject = {
  sequence: [1, 2, 3]
};

var accessSequence = scopeObject.sequence;
var mapping = accessSequence.map(mockResolve.bind(scopeObject));
console.log(mapping);
```

Is `namesSeq` just an array containing strings of those files? Without knowing for sure I'm guessing that it might be an array containing an array of file name strings, hence the error for an array of strings when it expected a string.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You are not paying attention to the callback expected by `Array.map`.</s>

Upon reading the [`docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you will discover that this is the syntax of the method:

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

As you can see, it will pass the entire array to the callback. This is why the solution you wanted does not work.

Your best solution without seeking the help of external libraries (like [`fp/lodash/`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide#mapping)) is your second to last option:

```
namesSeq.map(base => path.resolve.bind(dirPathAbs)(base));
```